# How to end a game after an interval of time(in XNA)

Tags: xna-4.0

I have created a game using XNA Game Studio. It consists of a square randomly moving anywhere and on clicking it, the score increases by one.

Now, what I want to do is, I want to end it after a time interval of, say, 100 seconds. So how do I do it? And where should I write that part of the code? That is, in which method? I am very new to XNA. Its just two days since I have started learning it.

Comment: May I know why this question was voted down? This is a genuine problem which I faced and voting it down just because you don't find it good enough is not going to help.

Comment: People usually vote down questions which don't at least show that you've tried to fix the problem yourself.  Usually you can do this by adding the code you have tried so far to the question.

Comment: It was probably voted down because you haven't posted any code or showed what you've tried to do.

Comment: But the thing is, I am new to XNA and I didnt have any idea at all about how to fix this thing which is why I posted it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your update loop check the elapsed game time greater than 100 seconds:

```
int counter = 0;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    counter += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    if ( counter > 100 )
    {
        //end the game...
    }
}
```

If you want the total game time since the game started, you can use the `TotalGameTime` property instead, then you won't need the counter.

Comment: Okay. And this is what I wanted. Its just a simple game. A sprite is created which moves about and you have to click it to increase your score. Just that. And the window closes after 100 seconds. Its just that

Comment: Great, if this is all you need please mark as accepted :)  If you need more help, update your question and I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks :) and one more thing is, How do I get the total time elapsed? Because the function which you've given in your code is giving me elapsed time since last update.

Comment: Create a counter in your game class, and each update loop just add the elapsed time since update to it.  See the updated answer

Comment: Also check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime_members.aspx You can use `ElapsedGameTime` for time since last update or `TotalGameTime` if you want time since game started.